# My project will be deployed on a server which has NO middleware. What is this mean?

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, middleware

I need help on java project deploying.

Here is the situation I am facing right now....

We are building a platform, this platform is planning to have 4 parts, actually 4 WAR files in the end. And these 4 WARs will be deployed in different servers, but the problem is that one WAR file (actually the core of our platform) will be deployed on a server which has no middleware, such as tomcat or weblogic etc.

So what does it mean that no middleware deploying, and how should other WARs communicate with this no middleware deployed WAR?? There is tons of data transmitting between different WARs.

Answer (score 0):

If there isn't an application server (or a servlet container), then your WAR will be just a big useless file sitting on the server. There's not much mystery here.

Comment: This is my first time meet this kind of situation. But my PM said so.

Comment: Either you misunderstood, or your PM doesn't know what he's talking about.

Comment: There are application on that server, OS is must, JVM too...  but just no middleware such as tomcat or weblogic, websphere..etc

Comment: Stop talking about middleware, it's like you just learned the word. A WAR file is deployed on a full blown application server or a servlet engine, that's where it runs. It can't run without one. End of story.

Comment: ok   Thanks anyway!  I said as same as yours to my PM, but he still insist his words. Maybe I misunderstood the issue!

Comment: You should ask him how he plans to run a file designed to run on an applications server, without one.

Comment: Sorry! My mistake!  That no middle deploying file is not a WAR file, it will be deployed as a JAR file.

Comment: Then there's no problem.